# how to list all aws regions in grails

Tags: amazon-web-services, grails

I have to list all `aws regions` in a `select` box by providing multiple select option.
I have added following plug-in

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:multi-select:0.2"
```

added following tag in `create.gsp` file

```
 <ui:multiSelect name="regions"
                    from="${}"
                    data-validation-error-msg="Please select one"
                    data-validation-error-msg-container="#multi_error"
                    noSelection="['':'Select One']"></ui:multiSelect>
```

How to display all regions , what is the value I have to provide for `from` attribute.

and the selected values should be stored in `Database` in a single `column` with comma(,) seperated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem,

```
<ui:multiSelect name="regions"
                from="${com.amazonaws.regions.Regions}"
                data-validation-error-msg="Please select one"
                data-validation-error-msg-container="#multi_error"
                noSelection="['':'Select One']"></ui:multiSelect>
```

used this Got list but not able to select multiple values. so used

```
<g:select name="region"  multiple="multiple" from="${com.amazonaws.regions.Regions}"  />
```

and this one getting selected values as a list and directly storing values in DB as comma seperated